# Current working directory problem with ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

Imagine you have a Node.js express server and your structure looks like this:

```js
app.mjs

services
-utils
--test.mjs


website
-js
--web.mjs
--req.mjs
-index.html
```

web.mjs:

```js
import * as req from '/js/req.mjs';
export const sample = ()=>{/*..*/};
export const sampletwo = ()=>{/*..*/};
```

index.html:

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as web from '/js/web.mjs';
</script>
```

This path works fine because the working directory comes from the index.html where we import web.mjs! However, when I want to read the web.mjs file Server Side then I get error **Cannot find module '/js/req.mjs'** because the working directory is different now.

test.mjs:

```js
import * as web from '../../website/js/web.mjs';
```

Is there a way to set the current working directory in ESM? Like you use CD in terminal. So that always when I try to read web.mjs it will use the working directory where the file itself is located?

Comment: FYI, the path resolver algorithm for `import` in nodejs is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolver_algorithm_specification).

Comment: FYI, "working directory comes from "index.html" when we open it in the browser is not the case at all for import within nodejs.

Comment: I added the example of the index.html! Client Side everything is working fine with the paths. However, I just want to Unit Test some of my Client Side js files (web.mjs) thats why I try to read them Server Side (test.mjs).

Comment: So, `index.html` will request `/js/web.mjs` from your server and it's totally up to your server to find that file in your file system and return it back to the browser.  You don't show any server code that would do that, but typically you would use something like `express.static()` to serve static resources and that would be configured with where to look.  None of that has anything at all to do with test.mjs loading some module server-side.

Comment: Is `test.mjs` running server-side or is it being loaded and run in the browser?

Comment: Yes I use app.use(express.static('./website')) inside of app.mjs! And yes test.mjs is loading Server Side by Mocha.js and has nothing to do with the Client Side files.

Answer (score -1):

Your code uses '/js/' as path, which is relative to root, not your project. To get the root path to your project use:

```
import { existsSync } from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

export function findPRoot() {
  let currentDir = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname

  while (true) {
    const packageJsonPath = `${currentDir}/package.json`
    if (existsSync(packageJsonPath)) {
      return currentDir
    }

    currentDir = path.dirname(currentDir)

    if (currentDir === '/') {
      return null
    }
  }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
~/.../src/utils
$ tsx
> const { findPRoot } = await import('./paths.ts')
> findPRoot()
'/home/runner/MyProject'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about setting the directory from which absolute import paths should be resolved